# How is it that material-ui modal component prevents resizing below width of modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I have been searching for a way to prevent a Chrome browser window from resizing my web-app below a certain width, when the app is viewed on a desktop.

Having said that, I recently noticed the material-ui modal component that I use for my login cannot be resized to less than its width when viewed in a regular browser window (but it can if viewed from a Chrome shortcut created by selecting "More tools --> Create shortcut..." and ticking off the "Open as window..." box).

My question is, what is it about the Material-UI modal that prevents resizing?  I would like to reproduce the behavior without doing something hacky like wrapping my entire app in a modal.

All of the threads I have read so far either indicate that most browser's no longer allow doing this, or contain solutions that do not work when I try them.

My modal code is here:
https://github.com/jehillert/timelockr-client/blob/master/src/components/forms/AuthModal.jsx

And a demo of that code may be found here:
https://timelockr.hillert.dev/

Note that the resizing behavior persisted even when I replaced the modal's children (i.e., the tab and dialog components) with an empty div.

Comment: Clarification: By "prevent a Chrome browser window from resizing...", I meant to say "prevent a user from resizing a Chrome browser..."

Comment: Far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Material-UI. No matter what the content is, Chrome seems to behave the same (for instance, I see the same behavior on my Chrome window displaying this StackOverflow page). Seems to prevent you from going smaller than 500px.

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot.  I only tried to compress the page with the modal, and did not think to check other pages or resize my modal.

Comment: Ryan, is it possible to mark your answer as the correct one or do you have to reenter your response in the main thread for me to be a be able to check it off?

Comment: I’ve moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Material-UI. No matter what the content is, Chrome seems to behave the same (for instance, I see the same behavior on my Chrome window displaying this StackOverflow page). Seems to prevent you from going smaller than 500px.